# mrsdeploy package not installed on Mac version of Microsoft R Open

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I need the `mrsdeploy` package to deploy remotely to `Microsoft R Server`.  I have this working on a local Windows machine where I have `Microsoft R Open` installed.  However, I have moved to a Mac, and have installed `Microsoft R Open` on it, and it seems like it should have the `mrsdeploy` package on it from what I've read, but it doesn't, and I cannot find a repo where I can get it from.  How can I get the `mrsdeploy` package installed on this R version on my Mac?

Details:

Startup Message:
        R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
        Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
        Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)

```
    R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
    You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
    Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

      Natural language support but running in an English locale

    R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
    Type 'contributors()' for more information and
    'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

    Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
    'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
    Type 'q()' to quit R.

    Microsoft R Open 3.5.1
    The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
    Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

    Multithreaded BLAS/LAPACK libraries detected. Using 4 cores for math algorithms.

    Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2018-08-01.
    See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

    [R.app GUI 1.70 (7405) x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0]
```

Session Info:

> sessionInfo()

```
    R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

    Matrix products: default
    BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

    locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] RevoUtils_11.0.1

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.5.1 tools_3.5.1
```

Installed packages:

```
    ip <- as.data.frame(installed.packages()[,c(1,3:4)])
    rownames(ip) <- NULL
    ip <- ip[is.na(ip$Priority),1:2,drop=FALSE]
    print(ip, row.names=FALSE)

        Package Version
     checkpoint   0.4.4
           curl     3.2
     doParallel  1.0.13
        foreach   1.5.0
      iterators  1.0.10
       jsonlite     1.5
     MicrosoftR 3.5.1.3
            png   0.1-7
             R6   2.2.2
        RevoIOQ  10.0.0
       RevoMods  11.0.1
      RevoUtils  11.0.1
          RUnit  0.4.26
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `mrsdeploy` does not come in Microsoft R Open. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-reference/mrsdeploy/mrsdeploy-package) has some information what it is distributed with. In addition to that, it is also part of Microsoft R Client. Unfortunately, Microsoft R Client is not available for Mac, only Windows and Linux.

Comment: Thank you Niels.  It's been a bit confusing figuring out how the client fits into this whole ecosystem, and what I can use to push to the server that I care about.  I have a workaround solution I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

As @nielsberglund has noted, Microsoft R Client is only available for Windows and Linux.  I thought the Microsoft R Open install would have a client with this package, but I was wrong (https://mran.microsoft.com/download).

My solution was to do the following:

- Run a VM with ubuntu 16.04 LTS on VirtualBox
- Follow the instructions for installing the client here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/r-client/install-on-linux
- Push my scripts to the VM and deploy from VM running on my Mac.

Running `R` there has the `mrsdeploy` package I need.  You may have to do further VM configurations with ports to make this work, and need to push your scripts to the VM or share directories where your scripts you use live.

My intent is to make this even lighter weight, and put together a Dockerfile based on the install instructions at the link above.  That would be a portable solution for anyone who can run Docker to be able to use the R Open Client.

```
# Install as root or sudo
sudo su

# If your system does not have the https apt transport option, add it now
apt-get install apt-transport-https

# Set the package repository location containing the R Client distribution. 
# On Ubuntu 14.04.
# wget http://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/14.04/prod/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 
# On Ubuntu 16.04.
wget http://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb 

# Register the repo.
dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb

# Check for microsoft-prod.list configuration file to verify registration.
ls -la /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

# Update packages on your system
apt-get update

# Install the packages
apt-get install microsoft-r-client-packages-3.4.3

# List the packages
ls /opt/microsoft/rclient/
```